# Find and replace string within a specific string with regex in visual studio

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010, replace, find

I'd like to replace automatically all the strings in my solution which are like this one

```
NotifyPropertyChanged("VariableParameter")
```

with this

```
NotifyPropertyChanged(Function() VariableParameter)
```

by "Quick Replace" in "Find and Replace" using a regular expression in Visual Studio 2010.

I have not the slightest idea how to do this when I have to keep each different variable parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following pattern and replacement.

**Pattern:** `NotifyPropertyChanged\("{[^"]+}"\)`

This matches your text, while escaping the parentheses. The `{[^"]+}` portion tags the contents (via the curly braces) and the `[^"]+` bit matches any character that isn't a double-quote, one or more times.

**Replacement:** `NotifyPropertyChanged(Function() \1)`

This replaces the matched text and is fairly straightforward to understand. The `\1` portion refers to the first (and only, in this example) tagged text from the pattern, which is the content between double-quotes.